Can we prove or disprove this expectation inequality?
Can we have this inequality under the assumption that $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 1$?
\begin{align}
\left( \mathbb{E}[X^4] + a^2 \right) \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X^2}{X^2 + a^2}\right] \geq 1.
\end{align}

I think we can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and prove it. I will write it.

Yes, this is an instance of the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality.

Simply replace $a^2$ in the first factor to $a^2\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ and this is CBS
